# binding data of a window in list view of a page

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

i'm coding in c#/wpf (i'm a beginner) and i want to show data in a page  listview ,i will be more clear i have a page contains listview and i have a window which contains textbox that i used it to do some treatement then i put the result in a variables which i want to show their values in the listview of the page 
here is what i tried

```
<GridViewColumn Width="180" Header="Quantité" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding quant}"/>
```

quant is a variable that i want to show it in the listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sofia,

in general Binding in WPF is like you have a DataContext (on Window/Control level) or an ItemsSource assigned to a specific Control.

I assume that you have got an `public ObservableCollection<T>` in your code behind class, eg. name `GridViewItemsSource` (due to mentioned ListView). Now you would set the ItemsSource of the GridView to the `GridViewItemsSource`. The T class has got a public property `quant`. Then it should work.

Eg. (INotifyPropertyChanged implementation is missing):

```
public class GenericData
{
  public string Quant {get; set;}
}
```

In your Window:

```
public ObservableCollection<GenericData> GridViewItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<GenericData>();
```

In your Window loaded:

```
  myGridView.ItemsSource = GridViewItemsSource;
```

Please watch the 'output' window from Visual Studio for Binding errors.